# Error al conectar mongodb://192.168.1.75:50001 Error Socket operation timed out docker-compose Sharding

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-compose, mongod

Estoy intentando hacer 2 sharding de una fragmentacion de mongo,
Estoy sigueindo un tutorial pero tengo un problema con la fragmentacion y la conexion a mongo de docker-compose y es que intento conectarme desde la terminar a otra maquina que esta en el docker-compose con el comando:

```
mongo mongodb://192.168.1.75:40001
```

el puerto si funciona ya que anteriormente ya me he podido conectar solo que ahora intento conectarme de nuevo y ya no funciona la coneccion
me  aparece el siguiente error:

```
$ mongo mongodb://192.168.1.75:40001
MongoDB shell version v5.0.7
connecting to: mongodb://192.168.1.75:40001/?compressors=disabled&gssapiServiceName=mongodb
Error: couldn't connect to server 192.168.1.75:40001, connection attempt failed: NetworkTimeout: Error connecting to 192.168.1.75:40001 :: caused by :: Socket operation timed out :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:372:17
@(connect):2:6
exception: connect failed
exiting with code 1
```

Considero que el probelma tiene que ver con docker-compose o la imagen de mongo o incluso el tcp de mi computadora solo que soy nuevo en esto

Ya intente desconectar el firewall de windows y vovler a intentarlo y no funciona pense que era el cortador de fuegos quien interumpia la conexion pero no

Este es mi config-server/docker-compose.yaml

```
version: '3.1'
services: 
    cfgsvr1: 
      container_name: cfgsvr1 
      image: mongo:4.4.6 
      command: mongod --configsvr --replSet cfgrs --port 27017 --dbpath /data/db 
      ports: 
        - 40001:27017
      volumes: 
        - cfgsvr1:/data/db 
    cfgsvr2:
      container_name: cfgsvr2 
      image: mongo:4.4.6 
      command: mongod --configsvr --replSet cfgrs --port 27017 --dbpath /data/db 
      ports: 
        - 40002:27017 
      volumes: 
        - cfgsvr2:/data/db 
    cfgsvr3: 
      container_name: cfgsvr3 
      image: mongo:4.4.6 
      command: mongod --configsvr --replSet cfgrs --port 27017 --dbpath /data/db
      ports: 
       - 40003:27017
      volumes: 
       - cfgsvr3:/data/db
volumes: 
  cfgsvr1: {}
  cfgsvr2: {}
  cfgsvr3: {}
```

Este es mi mongos/docker-compose.yaml

```
version: '3.1'
services:
  mongos:
    container_name: mongos
    image: mongo:4.4.6
    command: mongos --configdb cfgrs/192.168.1.75:40001,192.168.1.75:40002,192.168.1.75:40003 --bind_ip 0.0.0.0 --port 27017
    ports:
      - 60000:27017
```

Este es un shard1

```
version: '3.1'
services: 
  shard1svr1: 
    container_name: shard1svr1 
    image:  mongo:4.4.6
    command: mongod --shardsvr --replSet shard1rs --port 27017 --dbpath /data/db 
    ports: 
      - 50001:27017 
    volumes: 
      - shard1svr1:/data/db 
  shard1svr2: 
    container_name: shard1svr2 
    image:  mongo:4.4.6 
    command: mongod --shardsvr --replSet shard1rs --port 27017 --dbpath /data/db 
    ports: 
     - 50002:27017 
    volumes: 
    - shard1svr2:/data/db 
  shard1svr3: 
    container_name: shard1svr3 
    image: mongo:4.4.6
    command: mongod --shardsvr --replSet shard1rs --port 27017 --dbpath /data/db 
    ports: 
      - 50003:27017 
    volumes: 
     - shard1svr3:/data/db 
volumes: 
  shard1svr1: {}
  shard1svr2: {}
  shard1svr3: {}
```

Cuando ejecuto

```
docker ps
```

Estas son mis conecciones

```
$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE         COMMAND                  CREATED       STATUS       PORTS                                           NAMES
e45583e522ff   mongo:4.4.6   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   3 hours ago   Up 3 hours   0.0.0.0:60000->27017/tcp, :::60000->27017/tcp   mongos
0be2d50debcc   mongo:4.4.6   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   4 hours ago   Up 4 hours   0.0.0.0:50003->27017/tcp, :::50003->27017/tcp   shard1svr3
f84f930543b3   mongo:4.4.6   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   4 hours ago   Up 4 hours   0.0.0.0:50001->27017/tcp, :::50001->27017/tcp   shard1svr1
8108b8610c07   mongo:4.4.6   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   4 hours ago   Up 4 hours   0.0.0.0:50002->27017/tcp, :::50002->27017/tcp   shard1svr2
546ae670bc8b   mongo:4.4.6   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   4 hours ago   Up 4 hours   0.0.0.0:40001->27017/tcp, :::40001->27017/tcp   cfgsvr1
11ea1c1bbf6f   mongo:4.4.6   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   4 hours ago   Up 4 hours   0.0.0.0:40002->27017/tcp, :::40002->27017/tcp   cfgsvr2
9362a8a6b530   mongo:4.4.6   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   4 hours ago   Up 4 hours   0.0.0.0:40003->27017/tcp, :::40003->27017/tcp   cfgsvr3
```

He leido que algunos resolvieron este problema de esta forma

Donde haya instalado mongodb, simplemente debe ejecutar este comando en Linux
sudo sysctl -w net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_time=120

Sin embargo estoy usando docker-compose y mi terminar es una git bash
Pernse que era un problema tal vez de la imagen y me conecte por otra ip

```
mongo mongodb://127.0.0.1:40001
```

Ahi si me puede conectar pero repito ayer y antes ya me pude conectar con la Ip
192.168.1.75:4001

Answer (score 0):

Quisiera poner un comentario, pero como no tengo suficientes puntos, aquí te escribo como una respuesta

Cambie la IP de su sistema operativo y vea si todavía sucede. Si es
así, entonces tal vez la dirección IP de esa máquina fue incluida en
la lista negra por intentos fallidos de inicio de sesión o algo así.